# Salesforce to SFTP Server Integration

Tags: integration, sftp

Is it possible to Integrate Salesforce Directly to an SFTP Server? Has anyone already implemented this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Nope it isn't possible to do it directly. Salesforce supports only HTTP calls. You need some middleware to do it for you.

Comment: Thank you for answering! Can you give an example of middleware that I can use?

Comment: Java app on Heroku for example. Like any simple app which can be hosted. For example using JSch library (http://www.jcraft.com/jsch/)

Comment: I was thinking of Mule but not sure if that's doable

Comment: Of course it is! If you are using Mule already for something else, it is a natural choice